# How do I insert items in a multi submit form that contains also an array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to insert data into a few table with a single submit.
The problem is 2 of the table should be a few items (cooking  steps , Ingredients for the recipe )
The # of items in this 2 tables is unknown so I will use same ajax or any script Lib. But the problem is on the inserting to the db (db.add  & db.save)
each of  his 2 tables have one to many relation (one recipe many ….)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Recipe recipe, Category category, Ingredient ingredient ,  intrusion [] intrusion )
{

  int UserNumber = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
  recipe.UserId = UserNumber;
  recipe.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
  //intrusion  intrusion [] =new List<intrusion>  ;

  //var entity=new intrusion();
  //TryUpdateModel(entity ,new[] {"intrusion.IntrusionStep","intrusionId"});

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
  //   var results = db.intrusion.Add(entity);
    db.category.Add(category);
    db.recipe.Add(recipe);
    db.ingerdient.Add(ingredient);
    db.intrusion.Add(intrusion);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

  return View(recipe);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand...because you can to use a foreach for run the array of entities and add thats for the context and the db.SaveChanges is only in the finish

Comment: As it is now I have this Erorr MSG.The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSetXXX.Models.intrusion>.AddXXX.Models.intrusion)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you're passing in an array of `intrusion` records, yet still trying to use `db.intrusion.Add(intrusion);` to add them. You can't do that. `.Add()` only allows you to do one at a time (which explains your error message--it is invalid to put in the whole array).

If you actually are adding multiple intrusion objects you should actually do a `foreach` loop on that array as follows:

```
foreach(var i in intrusion)
{
  db.intrusion.Add(i);
}
```

That's as far as the error you mentioned in your comments goes. As far the one-to-many issue (**that you're not being very clear about**), make sure that the navigation property on the "many" entity points to the "one" entity, and make sure that the collection of the "many" entity on your "one" entity adds the reference to the "many" entity. EF should take care of the rest at that point.

Let me know if there's something that I've missed.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I have a diff error ,
Cannot implicitly convert type 'XXX.Models.intrusion' to 'int'
Why is it an int ?

Comment: Edited. Please take a look.

Comment: Ok I have a half backed solution.
I’m using this in my controller :
      public ActionResult Create(Recipe recipe, Category category, Ingredient ingredient, IEnumerable<Instructions> instrusion)
        {
//values